# Jenkins CI, how to add Importance property to EMail header?

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins

I would like Jenkins emails to have "Importance" icon (in Outlook)

If I generate the email manually - I can achieve this by adding these properties in the SMTP header:
Priority:High
Importance:high

Is there way to add them into Jenkins email headers? I could not find any plugin or option doing that :(

Answer (score 1):

No, this isn't currently possible, but you could probably add this to the [Email-ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin), which has configuration options for some other headers.

Comment: With The Email-ext Plugin you can create a custom subject and body for the e-mail, but I haven't found any option to change the importance of the e-mail...

Comment: not so difficult to implement, please raise issues in email-ext plugin

Answer (score 1):

There's a ticket requesting this feature in the Jenkins emailExt project: https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-69592?jql=labels%20%3D%20email-ext

One user listed a workaround in the comments there:

[image: workaround]

Code is just adding a presendScript `presendScript: '''msg.addHeader("X-Priority", "1")''')`